# NullReferenceException in SubSonic's 2.2 RecordBase.cs after Json request. Why?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, subsonic, nullreferenceexception

I have an MVC project that consumes a WCF service.  The service returns a collection of locations that is used to filter for autocomplete in a text box.

I initially tried this with with my own "Person" object to ensure I had the entire thing working.

jQuery call:

```
    $(function () {

        $("#txtGeoLocation").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/home/FindLocations", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.FullName, value: item.FullName, id: item.PersonId }
                            // return { label: item.GeoDisplay, value: item.GeoDisplay, id: item.GeoID }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.id)
                    : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            }
        });

    });
```

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FindNames(string searchText, int maxResults)
    {
        PersonRepository repository = new PersonRepository();
        var result = repository.FindPeople(searchText, maxResults);
        return Json(result);

    }
```

Person repository:

```
public class PersonRepository
{


    internal List<Person> FindPeople(string searchText, int maxResults)
    {

        List<Person> names = new List<Person>();

        BuildNameList(names);


        var result = from n in names
                     where n.FullName.Contains(searchText)
                     orderby n.FullName
                     select n;

        return result.Take(maxResults).ToList(); 
    }

    private static void BuildNameList(List<Person> names)
    {
        names.Add(new Person { PersonId = 1, FullName = "Kristina H. Chung" });
        names.Add(new Person { PersonId = 2, FullName = "Paige H. Chen" });
        names.Add(new Person { PersonId = 3, FullName = "Sherri E. Melton" });
```

Worked great... so I replaced my Json call from /home/FindNames to /home/FindLocations and uncommented the following line (commenting out the item.FullName line in my jQuery call):

```
return { label: item.GeoDisplay, value: item.GeoDisplay, id: item.GeoID }
```

Here is my controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FindLocations(string searchText, int maxResults)
    {
        GeoLocationRepository repository = new GeoLocationRepository();
        var result = repository.FindGeo(searchText, maxResults);

        return Json(result);    // returned a list collection of geo locations
    }
```

My repository method:

```
    internal List<FeederService.GeoLocation> FindGeo(string searchText, int maxResults)
    {
        // get geolocations from the cache

        var result = from l in HttpRuntime.Cache["WebsiteGeoLocations"] as FeederService.GeoLocationCollection
                     where l.GeoDisplay.Contains(searchText)
                     orderby l.GeoDisplay
                     select l;

        return result.Take(maxResults).ToList();
    }
```

Everything seems to work just fine until the end of the action method:

```
return Json(result);    // returned a list collection of geo locations
```

There is in fact the right collection with the right number of items in it, but nothing returned to my client.  VS pops up with the SubSonic file RecordBase.cs and a null reference exception at the get call of public string TableName:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the table in the database that contains persisted data for this type
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the table.</value>
    [XmlIgnore]
    [HiddenForDataBinding(true)]
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return BaseSchema.TableName; }  // <--- error occurs here
    }
```

Is this happening due to some entity reference issue, as I am the referencing FeederService.GeoLocation object and how can I get this to work?

The entities are all in a DAL project, referenced from and exposed through my FeederService:
GeoLocationCollection [CollectionDataContract]

```
[Serializable]
[CollectionDataContract]
public partial class GeoLocationCollection : ActiveList<GeoLocation, GeoLocationCollection>
{      
    public GeoLocationCollection() {}
```

And I've added [DataContract] to GeoLocation.

I have also placed "debugger;" in my jquery code (moved it into the function), but I am unable to debug the data returned.  How can I accomplish this?

Lastly, the issue only occurs when there is a match in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem, although not as elegant as I wanted it to be, and I would still like to know why I was having issues referencing a class exposed through my service.

For the solution, I created a WebsiteGeoLocation model class that has some of the properties of the FeederService.GeoLocation class.

I then iterated through the collection, and copied the values into my new local object.  Works just fine.  I will be moving the copy functionality into the caching method, so the object returned is always of the local type.

```
    List<WebsiteGeoLocation> geoList = null;

    internal List<WebsiteGeoLocation> FindGeo(string searchText, int maxResults)
    {
        // get geolocations from the cache

        var result = from l in HttpRuntime.Cache["WebsiteGeoLocations"] as FeederService.GeoLocationCollection
                     where l.GeoDisplay.Contains(searchText)
                     orderby l.GeoDisplay
                     select l;

        geoList = new List<WebsiteGeoLocation>();

        foreach (FeederService.GeoLocation location in result)
        {
            geoList.Add(new WebsiteGeoLocation
            {
                GeoID = location.GeoID,
                GeoDisplay = location.GeoDisplay,
                GeoCity = location.GeoCity,
                GeoState = location.GeoState,
                WebsiteID = location.WebsiteID,
                WorldCitiesID = location.WorldCitiesID
            });
        }

        return geoList.Take(maxResults).ToList();
    }
```